# Expand collapse UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableView Cell expand on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635338/uitableview-cell-expand-on-click)

i need help in UITableViewCell of UITableView.My requirement is below:

[image]

look at Retweets , list and More 
when i click retweet following appears
[image]

you can see that retweet expands and shows other listing and list and more slide below.
i want to make the same .
Any type of help is highly appreciated ,tutorial link or anything .
thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may also find [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code from Apple, helpful.

Comment: i have checkout your link , yes it is almost what i wanted,but it is a large program , so i am searching for alternative ,if not found anything , will definitely go with your idea. thanks a lot man , really appreciate it

Comment: @Kshitizyou can also achieve the functionality by using custom cells  easily, but my experience says the smooth experience that you'd get by this method wouldn't be achievable by that one.

Comment: thaken that in account , thank you once again

Comment: you ans is accepted man , at least i have place to start and there is what i want , i couldn't know what other guy is taking about

Answer (score 8):

I have implemented a similar one by using tableview header.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 32)];
    UIButton *sectionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    sectionButton.tag = section;
    sectionButton.frame = customView.frame;
    [sectionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 32)] autorelease];
    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSString *tableHeader = @"table_header_down.png";
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            titleLabel.text = @"Section1";
            tableHeader = showSection1 ? @"table_header_up.png" : @"table_header_down.png";
            break;
        case 1:
            titleLabel.text = @"Section2";
            tableHeader = showSection2 ? @"table_header_up.png" : @"table_header_down.png";
            break;
        case 2:
            titleLabel.text = @"Section3";
            tableHeader = showSection3 ? @"table_header_up.png" : @"table_header_down.png";
            break;
        case 3:
            titleLabel.text = @"Section4";
            tableHeader = showSection4 ? @"table_header_up.png" : @"table_header_down.png";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [sectionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tableHeader] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customView addSubview:sectionButton];

    [customView addSubview:titleLabel];

    return [customView autorelease];
}
```

Then I loaded the cell accordingly to the boolean values corresponding to each section, number of rows returns 0 if Bool 0, and returns the count when Bool 1.

Comment: i am late now , but will definitely check out your solution tomorrow , thanx

Comment: also, I forget to mention one thing, you may need to have some more thing to do in number if rows in section method. Return zero, if the boolean variable corresponding to that section is zero. In the button pressed method, I am switching the flag of the section between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

If you are an Apple developer, go to the WWDC videos and check out the advanced TableView video. It describes how to do exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: can you give me the link. yes i am apple developer

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092414566 Once you are in, go to Application frameworks and then to video 28, Mastering TableView

Answer (score 1):

i thought [this applelink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) helps you it's the great example of table view

Comment: your link and vin's link is the same, anyway thanx

Comment: [HVTableView](https://github.com/xerxes235/HVTableView): UITableView with expand/collapse feature