# Collapse Tableview Sections in UITableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can any one give me some advice or point me to any samples for how to achieve a collapsible UITableview sections effect in UITableView like accordian panel in web application?

Thanks

Comment: I have provided an answer for similar one in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190527/expand-collapse-uitableviewcell/5232091#5232091

Comment: Try this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview) to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides some sample code in his documentation for making a section collapse:

[Table View Animations and Gestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)