# How to create a combo box for the iPhone without using UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, combobox

I want to create a combo box for an iPhone application like we have on our website. I have searched a lot, but everybody says to use a picker. I want to use the same UI as a web combo box, so is there any way to do that in an iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a custom view with button and below that tableview. Set width of tableview similar to the width of button.

On button's event select or un-select tableview. And load the required data in tableview.

Using CALyer and other Core-graphics API, you can customize UI of table view as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [open-source implementation](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/combobox-for-uitableview) of what you're looking for. That site has a lot of useful, open source controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TableView and expand/collaps the Cells.

Here are some Examples...

[Expand collapse UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190527/expand-collapse-uitableviewcell/5190589#5190589)

and here...

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/