# Table Cell expansion laggy

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, tablecell

I have a custom table view & cell where a cell is expanded when selected. It is now functioning properly and accordingly. However, When I select cells to expand them, it takes about half a second to respond. The code below is located in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. **My hypothesis is that between beginUpdates and endUpdates, there are too many things going on to increase the height of the original cell and then updating the whole table view.** Is there another way I can better implement this?

```
**[_tableView beginUpdates];**

ReviewTestTableCell *reviewCell1 = (ReviewTestTableCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(reviewCell1.review.width, 900, reviewCell1.review.width, 900);

        CGRect textRectb = [reviewCell1.review textRectForBounds:rect limitedToNumberOfLines:1000];
        float labelHeight = textRectb.size.height;

        reviewCell1.review.height = labelHeight;
        expandHeight = labelHeight + 75 ;

        if ([[userdefaults objectForKey:@"merchantType"] isEqual:@"T"])
        {reviewCell1.height = labelHeight + 50;
        reviewCell1.bottomRatingView.height = reviewCell1.bottomRatingView.height - 20;

        }
        else
        {
            reviewCell1.height = labelHeight + 75;}

        reviewCell1.bottomRatingView.hidden = NO;
        reviewCell1.bottomRatingView.top = reviewCell1.review.bottom;

        **[_tableView endUpdates];**

       [_isExpandList replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@1];
    }
```

EDIT/ADD:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 UITableViewCell *cell3 = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([_isExpandList[indexPath.row]  isEqual: @1] && [[_dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Item1Score"] != nil) {

           return  cell3.height + 3 + 65;
}
else if ([_isExpandList[indexPath.row]  isEqual: @0])
{
return cell3.height +5;
}
else return cell3.height +3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not go through that elaborate dance of trying to manually expand the cell. You should certainly not manually call `willDisplayCell`.

Using the method described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635338/uitableviewcell-expand-on-click), you should have a property or something to keep track of which cell was selected and make your `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method adjust for that particular indexPath, then just call

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Which will call `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for every cell, which your method will give a larger height for when it matches the selected row. The tableView will smoothly adjust the height of your cell.

Something similar to:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        return 80.0f;
    }

    return tableView.rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, I've removed willDisplayCell and updated HeightForRowIndexPath, but it is still not smooth. Is there something wrong with my if statement in heightForRowIndexPath?