# UITableView design as in apple app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am looking to create a tableview that looks similar to the uitableview used in the appstore app (goto app store on apple device and select explore tab, here you will find categories table). Can any one suggest me how to do this. [Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v2x3gw7byjopvsq/Tableview%20demo.mov?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in different ways  simple way

first save the the selected cell index

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   self.selectedRowIndex = [indexPath];
   [tableView reload];

}
```

then when increase the height for selected row like this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //check if the index actually exists
   if(selectedRowIndex && indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row) {
        return 100;
   }
   return 44;
}
```

for reference  [Accordion table cell - How to dynamically expand/contract uitableviewcell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066167/accordion-table-cell-how-to-dynamically-expand-contract-uitableviewcell)

you can use libraries also have a look at

http://code4app.net/category/tableview

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jkexpandtableview

[UITableViewCell expand on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635338/uitableviewcell-expand-on-click)