# How to implement the expandable list to show the details when clicked on a cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, expandablelistview

I want to implement the expandable list in iOS as in Android where the use clicks on any cell of the UITableView and the cell expands to show the rest of the details. For example, I am showing few questions on each table view cell. On clicking the table view cell it expands to show the answers under the question.
Sample Image which i want to acheive is as:
[image: Expandable Cell]

Comment: user below swift library to make this features like https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kjexpandabletabletree

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635338/uitableviewcell-expand-on-click

Answer (score -1):

implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` , and when you touch to cell , change height row property and reload data.